# Why is the viewport met-tag not working as expected

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, responsive, meta-tags

Im having some problems with this web page that I am building out. The code is pasted below but you can also take a look at it here: www.petermingione.com/Webcast2/

When the page loads on mobile devices the page is zoomed in and I have to pinch to get the zoom to the initial scale. I am confused as to why this is happening since I have included the viewport meta-tag:

Thank you very much for any help that you can give me. Pete

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us"> 

<head>
    <title>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- strongly recommended by the Bootstrap -->
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="app.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header class="header">
            <div class="tbl-row">
                <div class="header-left">
                    <h1>
                        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing</span><br/>
                          Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat<br/>        
                          Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum 
                    </h1>
                </div>
                <div class="header-spacer"></div>   
                <div class="header-right">  
                    <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="small-box"></div>

        <!-- CENTER TABLE -->
        <div class= "center-table">
            <!-- CENTER ROW -->
            <div class= "center-row">

                <div class="vert-spacer"></div>

                <!-- MAIN -->
                <main>
                    <div class="main-body">
                        <div class="main-body-header">
                            <p><strong>WEBCAST</strong>TRANSMITTED LIVE ON</p>
                            <p>Sunday, 9 December 2018, 3:00 (EST) from New York, NY</p>
                            <div class="hr"></div>
                            <p><strong>Webcast:</strong><em>To View From Your Home or Office, Register at:</em></p>
                            <p>www.irure dolor in reprehenderit.com</p>
                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore.</p>

                        </div>
                        <p class="foot-note">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud.</p>
                        <p class="co-chairs"><span>Co-Chairs:</span> John Jones (Brazil), George Orwell (London, England)</p>
                        <table class="table">
                            <thead>
                              <tr class="header">
                                <th colspan="3">agenda</th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>09:00 – 09:05</td>
                                    <td>Welcome and Introduction</td>
                                    <td>Co-Chairs</td>
                                </tr>      
                                <tr>
                                    <td>09:05 – 09:30</td>
                                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</td>
                                    <td>John Jones</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="qa">
                                    <td>09:30 – 09:35</td>
                                    <td colspan="2">Q&A</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>09:35 – 10:00</td>
                                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</td>
                                    <td>George Orwell</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="qa">
                                    <td>10:00 – 10:05</td>
                                    <td colspan="2">Q&A</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>10:05 – 10:30</td>
                                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</td>
                                    <td>Who Cares</td>
                                </tr>
                                    <tr class="qa">
                                    <td>10:30 – 10:35</td>
                                    <td colspan="2">Q&A</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="break">
                                    <td>10:35 – 11:05</td>
                                    <td colspan="2">Break</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>11:05 – 11:30</td>
                                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</td>
                                    <td>Sam Man</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr class="qa">
                                    <td>11:30 – 11:35</td>
                                    <td colspan="2">Q&A</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>11:35 – 12:35</td>
                                    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt</td>
                                    <td>Faculty</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>12:35 – 12:45</td>
                                    <td>Closing Remarks</td>
                                    <td>Co-Chairs</td>
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                         </table>
                         <!-- /table -->
                    </div>
                        <!-- /main-body -->
                </main>
                <!-- /MAIN -->

                <!-- ASIDE -->
                <aside>
                    <div class="main-body">
                        <p class="list-header">Co-Chairs</p>
                        <ul class="faculty-list">
                            <li>
                                <span>John Jacob</span><br/>
                                Expert in Stuff<br/>
                                Lorum ipsum Division<br/>
                                Department of Lorem Ipsum<br/>
                                200 Car Talk Tower, Dewey Cheatum & Howe<br/>
                                Cambridge, MA
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <span>John Jacob</span><br/>
                                Expert in Stuff<br/>
                                Lorum ipsum Division<br/>
                                Department of Lorem Ipsum<br/>
                                200 Car Talk Tower, Dewey Cheatum & Howe<br/>
                                Cambridge, MA
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <p class="list-header">faculty</p>
                        <ul class="faculty-list">
                            <li>
                                <span>John Jacob</span><br/>
                                Expert in Stuff<br/>
                                Lorum ipsum Division<br/>
                                Department of Lorem Ipsum<br/>
                                200 Car Talk Tower, Dewey Cheatum & Howe<br/>
                                Cambridge, MA
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span>John Jacob</span><br/>
                                Expert in Stuff<br/>
                                Lorum ipsum Division<br/>
                                Department of Lorem Ipsum<br/>
                                200 Car Talk Tower, Dewey Cheatum & Howe<br/>
                                Cambridge, MA
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span>John Jacob</span><br/>
                                Expert in Stuff<br/>
                                Lorum ipsum Division<br/>
                                Department of Lorem Ipsum<br/>
                                200 Car Talk Tower, Dewey Cheatum & Howe<br/>
                                Cambridge, MA
                            </li>

                            <li>
                                <span>John Jacob</span><br/>
                                Expert in Stuff<br/>
                                Lorum ipsum Division<br/>
                                Department of Lorem Ipsum<br/>
                                200 Car Talk Tower, Dewey Cheatum & Howe<br/>
                                Cambridge, MA
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /main-body -->
                </aside>
                <!-- /ASIDE -->

            </div>
            <!-- /CENTER ROW -->

        </div>
        <!-- /CENTER TABLE -->

        <!-- FOOTER -->
        <footer>
            <p>
                Copyright © 2018 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt<br/>      
                XXX-999999-YY 
            </p>
            <div class="logo">LOGO GOES HERE</div>
        </footer>
        <!-- /FOOTER-->
    </div>
    <!-- /container -->

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font-size: 16px;
}

html, body, p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: "Arial Narrow", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-size: 1rem;
}

p {
  line-height: 1;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  padding: 0;
  max-width: 1239px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: -137px;
  width: fit-content;
}

header {
  display: table;
  vertical-align: top;
  height: 200px;
  z-index: 1004;
}

.header-left {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 78%;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #00948f;
  box-shadow: 7px 15px 18px #aaa;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 15px 18px #aaa;
  position: relative;
}
.header-left h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-size: 3.125rem;
  margin: 0;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  background-color: #00948f;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 85px 30px 138px;
  line-height: 1.1;
  margin: 0;
}
.header-left h1 span {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-size: 1.875rem;
  line-height: 1;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.header-spacer {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 2%;
}

.header-right {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 21%;
  background-color: #9fd2d0;
  box-shadow: 7px 15px 18px #aaa;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 7px 15px 18px #aaa;
  z-index: 1002;
  padding: 175px 61px 0 20px;
  line-height: 1.3;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
}

.small-box {
  width: 8%;
  height: 33px;
  background-color: #9fd2d0;
  z-index: 1005;
  padding: 0;
}

.center-table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.center-row {
  display: table-row;
}

.vert-spacer {
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: #e6e7e8;
  z-index: -2;
  width: 8%;
}

main {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 69%;
}

.main-body {
  margin-left: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}
.main-body p:first-child {
  font-size: 44px;
  font-size: 2.75rem;
}
.main-body p:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 27px;
  font-size: 1.6875rem;
}
.main-body .hr {
  border-top: 10px solid white;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
.main-body p:nth-child(3) {
  font-size: 27px;
  font-size: 1.6875px;
}

.main-body-header {
  background-color: #9fd2d0;
  padding: 10px 25px 15px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.main-body-header p:first-child {
  font-size: 44px;
  font-size: 2.75rem;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.main-body-header p:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 27px;
  font-size: 1.6875rem;
}
.main-body-header hr {
  border-width: 10px;
}
.main-body-header p:nth-child(4) {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-size: 1.875rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.main-body-header p:nth-child(5) {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.main-body-header p:nth-child(6) {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.foot-note {
  font-size: 20px !important;
  font-size: 1.25rem !important;
  margin-bottom: 1.25rem;
}

.co-chairs {
  font-size: 22px !important;
  font-size: 1.375rem !important;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.co-chairs span {
  color: #00837c;
}

table {
  font-size: 23px;
  font-size: 1.4375rem;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
table th {
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
table tr td {
  padding: 5px;
}
table tr td:first-child {
  width: 20%;
}
table tr td:nth-child(2) {
  width: 55%;
}
table tr td:nth-child(3) {
  width: 25%;
  text-align: right;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
table tr.header {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-size: 1.75rem;
  background-color: #00948f;
  color: white;
}
table tr.header th {
  border-top: 5px solid black;
}
table tr:not(agenda) td {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #00948f;
}
table tr.qa {
  background-color: #e5f4f4;
}
table tr.break {
  background-color: #cdeae9;
}

aside {
  padding: 0 20px;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 21%;
  text-align: top;
}
aside .list-header {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #004a99;
  font-size: 28px !important;
  font-size: 1.75rem !important;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
aside .faculty-list {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
  color: #a0a0a0;
}
aside .faculty-list li {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
aside .faculty-list li span {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-size: 1.277777778rem;
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 137px;
  z-index: 10000;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 420px;
  background-color: #00948f;
  width: 100%;
  height: 402px;
  z-index: -2;
}
footer p {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  bottom: 30px;
  font-size: 19px;
  font-size: 1.1857rem;
  line-height: 1.3;
}
footer .logo {
  position: absolute;
  right: 60px;
  bottom: 30px;
  width: 90px;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #9fd2d0;
  display: inline-block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .header-left,
  .header-right {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
  }

  .header-left {
    margin: 0 20px;
  }
  .header-left h1 {
    font-size: 40px !important;
    font-size: 2.5rem !important;
    padding: 20px !important;
  }
  .header-left h1 span {
    font-size: 15px !important;
    font-size: 0.9375rem !important;
  }

  .header-right {
    padding: 20px !important;
    margin: 30px 20px 0;
  }

  .small-box {
    display: none;
  }

  .vert-spacer {
    display: none;
  }

  main, aside {
    display: block;
    width: auto;
  }

  .main-body {
    margin: 20px;
  }

  .main-body-header p:first-child {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 40px;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1120px) {
  footer p {
    bottom: 100px;
  }
  footer .logo {
    right: auto;
    left: 20px;
    bottom: 5px;
  }
}
```

Comment: what browser / device are you testing?

Comment: iPhone 6 Plus using the latest safari browser

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try to make it maximum scale to 0. However, it will disable the zoom feature. you cannot pinch out to zoom.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

Comment: Good idea but it didn't work. Not only is it still zoomed in initially, but t also did not disable the zoom feature. I am not sure why.

Comment: did you try putting a minimum-scale=1?